# 'ds' is not defined no-undef

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have few DIV elements which I make selectable using DRAGSELECT library.
In the componentDidMount,

```
componentDidMount() {
      var ds = new DragSelect({
    selectables: document.getElementsByClassName('ele-select'),
    area: document.getElementById('canvas'),
    onElementSelect: (element) => {
      var idArray = [];
      idArray.push(ds.getSelection())
     this.check(idArray)
    }
  })
    $('.text').draggable({
      cursor: 'move'
    })

    $('#canvas').on('mousedown', '.main-container',  (e) => {
      if ($(e.target).attr('class').indexOf('main-container') > -1) {
        this.unwrapAll()
        ds.start()
      } else {
        //idArray = []
        ds.stop();
        ds.break();
      }
    })
    $('#canvas').on('mouseup', function (e) {
      //idArray = []
      ds.stop();
      ds.start()
    })
  }
```

This results in error that: 'ds' is not defined  no-undef

However I fixed the error using - /* eslint no-undef: 0 */ // --> OFF
at the top of component.

Now when I try add a new element and make it selectable it throws:
ReferenceError: ds is not defined.

I'm preety sure this is due to variable scope as var have functional scope.
 But where should I declare it then? even tried inside constructor but doesn't seems to work.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import $ from 'jquery'
import 'jquery-ui/ui/widgets/draggable';
import DragSelect from 'dragselect';
import Button from './components/Button/Button'

/* eslint no-undef: 0 */ // --> OFF
class App extends Component {
 state = {
   btn: ['Add Element', 'Wrap', 'Unwrap']
 }
  componentDidMount() {
      var ds = new DragSelect({
    selectables: document.getElementsByClassName('ele-select'),
    area: document.getElementById('canvas'),
    onElementSelect: (element) => {
      var idArray = [];
      idArray.push(ds.getSelection())
     this.check(idArray)
    }
  })
    $('.text').draggable({
      cursor: 'move'
    })

    $('#canvas').on('mousedown', '.main-container',  (e) => {
      if ($(e.target).attr('class').indexOf('main-container') > -1) {
        this.unwrapAll()
        ds.start()
      } else {
        //idArray = []
        ds.stop();
        ds.break();
      }
    })
    $('#canvas').on('mouseup', function (e) {
      //idArray = []
      ds.stop();
      ds.start()
    })
  }


clickHandler = (val) => {
if(val === 'Add Element'){
  this.addElement();
}
}
addElement = () => {
  var x = $('.text:last')
  var top = parseFloat(x.css('top').slice(0, -2))
  x = x.attr('id').slice(-1)
  $('.main-container').append("<div class='text ele-select'>" +Math.random()+ "</div>")
  $('.text:last').attr('id', 'text' + (++x))
  $('.text:last').css({
      'top': top + 27
  })
  $('.text:last').draggable({
      cursor: 'move'
  })
 ds.addSelectables(document.getElementsByClassName('ele-select'));
}
  render() {
    var button = this.state.btn.map((element,i) => {
      return <Button value={element} clicked = {() => this.clickHandler(element)} key={i + element}/>
    })
    return (
      <div>
       {button}
      <div id='canvas'>
        <div className="main-container">
          <div className="text ele-select" id='text1' draggable="true">Some text</div>
          <div className="text ele-select" id='text2' draggable="true">Another text</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default App;
```

Comment: If `ds` is only used within the class you can define a class member - even declare it private if only used there. `class App extends Component { private ds: DragSelect; ...`

Comment: @RandyCasburn can you please elaborate abit on this!!

Comment: Put your app in the React playground or someplace that provides a working solution and I'll be glad to help.

Comment: The problem you are facing is because `ds` is defined only inside `componentDidMount`. You might want look into how `var` works. [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)

**a simpler approach would be to replace with `var ds =  ` with `this.ds = `. **

Comment: also i would strongly don't recommend using jquery with react.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Use this - https://codesandbox.io/s/zlopqq9x7m

Comment: @BalavishnuVJ doesn't works

Comment: @Adarsh, checked your codebox. It throws cross-origin error.

Comment: @BalavishnuVJ you can enable CORS through chrome extension

Comment: issue isn't wasn't with cors. You have server `serviceWorker` isn't defined as you commented out the import.

Comment: also after replacing with `var ds = with this.ds = ` did you change all occurance of `ds` with `this.ds`?

Comment: @BalavishnuVJ Changed at all occurance